# Drools detect multiple matches from one array to another

Tags: java, drools

I have two arrays within an object Colors.

```
private String[] colorArray = {"blue", "red", "yellow", "green"};
private String[] myColors = {"blue", "red", "purple"};
```

I want to be able to detect if there is more than one match within the other array.

```
rule "check if inside array"
    when
        Colors($colors: getMyColors())
        $color: String() from $colors
        Colors(getColorArray() contains $color)
    then
        System.out.println("Color found once in array");
end
```

So for my example, I would like to detect if "blue" and "red" are found within the colorArray. I dont know if there is a way to autoincrement a variable with the LHS so I can detect that 2 colors where found.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it have to be arrays? Care to continue the discussion with this data being stored as Collections - Set, preferably?

Comment: It can be stored in any Collections, they are in fact stored in ArrayList<String>. I just put them in an array to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write a DRL function:

```
function int cardInter( Collection a, Collection b ){
    ArrayList x = new ArrayList( a );
    x.retainAll( b );
    return x.size();
}
```

and call it:

```
rule "check if inside array"
when
    Colors($a: myColors, $b: colorArray )
    eval( cardInter( $a, $b ) > 1 )
then
    System.out.println( "Color found more than once" );
end
```

Most of the time, arrays make it more difficult than any of the Collections. Note that the DRL function could be easily extended for arrays, though.

Comment: Thanks for finding the missing result type. int will do.